# Confusing database with schema

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I have defined db name in squelize constructor so that tables being generated by corresponding model files. Tables are successfully created in given db. I am confused with the schema which by default is public in models.So why to define schema in models if tables are properly generated in db in default postgresql server named PostgreSQL 15. if I change name of schema from public to some how ALGH it says schema doesnot exist. if it is referencing schema then what is the purpose of giving db name in sequelize constructor.

Answer (score 2):

You can have multiple schemas in the same DB for different purposes like to divide sets of tables for different apps/services or by functionality.
You can indicate a schema in the Sequelize instance and it will be the default schema for all models that does not have an explicit schema **OR** you can indicate a schema for certain models only and other models will have the default `public` schema.
Of course, you need to create tables only **after** you decided and indicated all schemas (either in Sequelize instance and/or in certain models) you need otherwise you will get such errors you already mentioned in the post.

Comment: actually in the sequelize constructor. documentation is written as to put database, username and pass not schema is written any where. which i was confusing. this might be they are generalizing describing every thing. However i did not find any way to add schema in sequelize instance but find creation of schema separately. BTW your answer helped me. thanks

Comment: Look at options passed while crating Sequelize instance